# A matrix equation with real coefficients

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis, lagrange-multiplier, multilinear-algebra

The problem is the following: Find $\lambda$ such that

$
b^{T}A\left[A^{T}A-\lambda L^{T}L\right]^{-1}L^{T}L\left[A^{T}A-\lambda L^{T}L\right]^{-1}A^{T}b-\delta^{2}<0
$

where $\lambda,\delta\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\delta>0,$ and we have
that $A\in M_{m\times n}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, $L\in M_{n\times n}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$
and $b\in M_{m\times1}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$.
The idea is find a expression for $\lambda$ in terms of $A,$ $L$
and $b$.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The task is not clear. I can choose $\lambda $ big enough to satisfy it.Becasue when $\lambda \to \infty$ we have $b^TA(L^TL)^{-1}A^Tb<\delta^2\lambda^2$

Comment: Nete that the term $b^{T}A\left[A^{T}A-\lambda L^{T}L\right]^{-1}L^{T}L\left[A^{T}A-\lambda L^{T}L\right]^{-1}A^{T}b$ is an matrix of size $1\times1$, but an matrix of size $1\times1$ can be considered as a number.

Comment: So what did you want to say? The fact that 1x1 matrix is a number does not help me to understand what you really want to see. The minimal $\lambda$? The set of all $\lambda$?

Comment: you are right, the aim is to find the set of all the $\lambda$ such that satisfy the inequality.

Comment: Any restriction on $\lambda$ ? $>0$? Rank of $A,L$?

Comment: There are no restrictions in terms of the problem.

Comment: What I mean is that there are no additional restrictions on the terms of the problem.

Comment: But for some $\lambda$ matrix becomes singular and for some $A$ $L$ it is singular for any $\lambda$.